# Find vertices coordinates of regular pentagon given one of the coordinates and centre

Tags: geometry, angle, polygons

I need to find the vertex coordinates of a pentagon given that one of the coordinates is $(1,0)$ and that the centre of the pentagon is located at $(0,0)$?

This is to be done only by using geometry (and trigonometry), without using complex numbers. This can possibly be done by splitting sectors into triangles and using trigonometry with the $72°$ and $108°$ angles, however I am unsure how to proceed.

Let $B  = (1, 0)$ and center $(0,0)$:
[image]

Comment: Do you know complex numbers? It is really easy using these.

Comment: As @MyMolecules says, complex numbers make this easy but simple division of $2\pi$ by $5$ and trigonometry works too.

Comment: @JohnDouma , I need to use geometry and trigonometry so I have to use 2π/5 . However I can't figure out how to find all of the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the axes and center $O=(0,0)$

From $B$, drop perpendicular $BP$ onto x-axis and look at the right triangle formed. Point $B$ will have abscissa of length $OP = OB\cos \theta_B$ and ordinate equal to length $BP = OB\sin \theta_B$. In addition we need to be careful with signs. Since $B$ is in first quadrant, its coordinates will have signs $(+,+)$. Conclude
$$B=(+OB\cos \theta_B, +OB\sin \theta_B)$$

[image]

Now resorting to geometry, $\theta_B = \angle AOX - \angle AOB=90^\circ - 72^\circ = 18^\circ$. As $OB=1$,
$$B=(+\cos 18^\circ, +\sin 18^\circ)$$

Similarly you can find coordinates of $C,D,E$.

**Remark :**

I found coordinates of $B$ for the condition $A=(0,1)$, which was mentioned in an earlier version of this post. However if it is given $B=(1,0)$, then question becomes even easier; same concept applies. Find the angle corresponding to each vertex and then append proper signs to abscissa and ordinates.

Comment: I wonder why this is a difficult question for the OP. However, as B(1,0), ED should be vertical. In other words, OB is horizontal.

Comment: @ACB This is weird. Before this post was closed, OP wrote $A=(0,1)$ and now they have given diagram corresponding to that and I answered according to that. I am only seeing now they have written $B=(1,0)$.